# The present progressive to talk about the future

Tags: sentence-meaning, present-continuous

Suppose we ask the following question:

> Did you know I'm getting a new job?

Does it suggest that I've already found the job but probably not started yet. I mean can this meaning be possible in some context?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are right. But *get* is not the best verb for this kind of activity (though it is often used), and as you surmised the true meaning is not so clear.
As you mentioned, *found* is probably a better verb to use:

> Did you know I **found** a new job?

If you had started the job:

> Did you know I **started** a new job?

And if you had not found a new job yet:

> Did you know I'm **looking for** a new job?

Answer (score 2):

> Did you know I'm getting a new job?

Does it suggest that I've **already found the job but probably not started yet?** ~ *No, it does not!*

But for the Title of the question: Present progressive for the future event - YES, it's possible.

To mean that you already have a job but not going, you need to *clarify* that

> Do you know I already have a job... *(but for 'x' reason, I haven't joined yet...or whatever)*.

*I'm getting a new job* talks about the process. Maybe, you are selected and about to get a '[joining letter](http://www.letters.org/miscellaneous-letter/employment-joining-letter.html)'.