# What exactly does "doing something for the xth time in y hours" mean?

Tags: numbers, time

I had always used the present perfect tense for sentences such as "have done something x times in the last y hours" until I came across the following sentence:

"I'm eating pancakes for the fourth time in 6 hours"

Does it mean:

1)I'm eating pancakes for the 4th time in the last 6 hours (I have eaten pancakes thrice in the last 6 hours, and now I'm eating them for the fourth time in the same time period)

2)I will be eating pancakes for the 4th time in 6 hours time (will happen in the future)

Similarly, "I'm playing fifa for the second time in 4 hours"

1)I'm playing fifa for the second time in the last 4 hours (I have played it once in the last 4 hours, and now I'm playing it for the second time in the same time period)

2)I will be playing fifa for the second time in 4 hours time ( will happen in the future)

Also, I'm not sure whether (1) is grammatically correct. Present continuous doesn't sound correct some reason.

Comment: It is the first option in each example.  I can't tell you exactly why, but I can say that to a native speaker, the intended meaning is that you have done something x times in the past y hours. If you said for the first time in x hours, you would be talking about the future.

Comment: You already answered your question. Because you used "I'm eating/playing" in your examples, it has to be 1) which uses the same form. You would have to use "I will be eating/playing" in order to match the meanings in 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example

> **I'm eating pancakes for the fourth time in 6 hours**
>   *I am eating*

is present tense and so you would say this while you are eating pancakes (your fourth time).

Prior to sitting down and eating more pancakes

> I have eaten pancakes 3 times in the past 6 hours.
>   I had eaten pancakes 3 times in the past 6 hours.
>   I had pancakes 3 times in the past 6 hours.
>   I had pancakes for the third time in 6 hours about half an hour ago.
>
> But I'm still hungry, so I'll have some more.

While you are eating the pancakes

> I am having pancakes for the fourth time in 6 hours.
>   I am eating pancakes for the fourth time in 6 hours.
>   *I'm stuffing my face again for the fourth time in 6 hours.*

after you have finished with this last session of pancakes

> I **have eaten** pancakes for the fourth time in the last 6 hours.
>   I **have had** pancakes four times in the last 6 hours.
>   I **had** pancakes for the fourth time in 6 hours, not so hungry anymore.

Answer (score 3):

It probably means #1,
but it could mean #2 in reference to the immediate or near future. 
The fact that your sentence establishes a short time frame (six hours)
allows this usage.

@Peter and @user3169 say that the sentence must mean *now* (meaning #1)
because “I’m eating pancakes” is present tense. 
I dispute this. 
The present continuous (also known as [present progressive](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/6308/26083))
can be used to refer to events in the near future.

> We are having pancakes for supper.

doesn't necessarily mean that we are eating supper ***right now***
(and so I’m talking with my mouth full);
it can mean “We **will be** having pancakes for supper *this evening*.” 
Similarly,

> Tomorrow, I’m asking my boss for a raise.

and

> We’re taking a vacation next month.

are acceptable, clearly understandable examples
of using the present continuous to refer to events in the future.

References:

- [Present continuous and simple future](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/127908/26083) (EL&U)
- [When do I use Present Continuous for near future
  instead of “be going to”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/235368/26083) (EL&U)
- [future continuous vs. present progressive](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/43876/357) (ELL)
- [Present tense for future events](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/29141/26083) (EL&U)
- [Present Simple vs. Present Continuous for future actions](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/234840/26083) (EL&U)
- [“I am going to attend” vs. “I am attending”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/102621/26083) (EL&U)
- [The present progressive to talk about the future](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/43243/357) (ELL)
- [“What do you do on Sundays?” vs. “What are you doing on Sunday?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/291991/26083) (EL&U)
- [Difference between future and present continuous in “going”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/97533/26083) (EL&U)
- [Present Continuous or Present Simple in a Meeting](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/54831/26083) (EL&U)